# Block cut from contextmenu using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-5

I need block the option "cut" (only this option) from contextmenu.

I only found how to block all the contextmenu using `oncontextmenu="return false"` but not a single option.

**HTML:**

```
            <input id="origenInput" name="origen" list="origen" placeholder="Seleccione origen"
                oncontextmenu="return false">
            <datalist id="origen">
            </datalist>

            <input id="destinoInput" name="destino" list="destino" placeholder="Seleccione destino"
                disabled>
            <datalist id="destino">
            </datalist>
            <br><br>
            <span id="textoPrecio"></span>
            <br><br>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
ejecutarMultiplesEventos(document.getElementById("destinoInput"), 'change keyup', mostrarInfoPasaje);

(function cargarListadoOrigen() {    let origenOption = "";

let origen = ["Amarillo", "Río Alfa"];

for (let i = 0; i < origen.length; ++i) {
    origenOption += '<option value="' + origen[i] + '" />';
}

let origenLista = document.getElementById("origen");
origenLista.innerHTML = origenOption;})();

function cargarListadoDestino() {
document.getElementById("textoPrecio").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("destinoInput").value = "";
document.getElementById("destinoInput").disabled = true;

let destinoOption = "";
let destino = null;
let destinoLista = null;

let origenSeleccionado = obtenerOrigenIngresado();

if (origenSeleccionado.length >= 3) {
    switch (origenSeleccionado) {
        case "Amarillo":
            destino = ["Barrio Nuevo"];

            for (let i = 0; i < destino.length; ++i) {
                destinoOption += '<option value="' + destino[i] + '" />';
            }

            destinoLista = document.getElementById("destino");
            destinoLista.innerHTML = destinoOption;
            document.getElementById("destinoInput").disabled = false;
            break;

        case "Río Alfa":
            destino = ["El Valle", "Tucute"];

            for (let i = 0; i < destino.length; ++i) {
                destinoOption += '<option value="' + destino[i] + '" />';
            }

            destinoLista = document.getElementById("destino");
            destinoLista.innerHTML = destinoOption;
            document.getElementById("destinoInput").disabled = false;
            break;


        default:
            document.getElementById("textoPrecio").innerHTML = "El origen ingresado es inválido."
            document.getElementById("destinoInput").value = "";
            document.getElementById("destinoInput").disabled = true;
            break;
    }
}}

function mostrarInfoPasaje() {
    document.getElementById("textoPrecio").innerHTML = "";
    let origenSeleccionado = document.getElementById("origenInput").value;
    let destinoSeleccionado = document.getElementById("destinoInput").value;
    let texto = "El viaje de " + origenSeleccionado + " a " + destinoSeleccionado + " tiene un costo de $";
    let valor = obtenerPrecio();

    if (destinoSeleccionado.length >= 3) {
        switch (origenSeleccionado) {
            case "Amarillo":
                if (destinoSeleccionado === "Barrio Nuevo") {
                    document.getElementById("textoPrecio").innerHTML += texto + valor + ".";
                } else if (destinoSeleccionado === "") {
                    document.getElementById("textoPrecio").innerHTML = "";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("textoPrecio").innerHTML = "El destino ingresado es inválido."
                }
                break;

            case "Río Alfa":
                if (destinoSeleccionado === "El Valle") {
                    document.getElementById("textoPrecio").innerHTML += texto + valor + ".";
                } else if (destinoSeleccionado === "Tucute") {
                    document.getElementById("textoPrecio").innerHTML += texto + valor + ".";
                } else if (destinoSeleccionado === "") {
                    document.getElementById("textoPrecio").innerHTML = "";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("textoPrecio").innerHTML = "El destino ingresado es inválido."
                }
                break;

            default:
                try {
                    console.error("mostrarInfoPasaje > default");
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log("Catch: ");
                    console.log(e);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    }
```

The original problem I want to solve is the following (perhaps there is another easier solution): I have two datalists, the second datalist shows the options depending on what is selected in the first, and according to the combination entered I show a text in a `<span>`, in case the user selects the text entered in the second datalist and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, the `<span>` is updated correctly, but if the user selects the text entered in the second datalist, right click and select CUT, the `<span>` is not updated.

Comment: You can't do it

Comment: I know some websites *do* do it.  Maybe they just overwrite the clipboard when they detect a copy/cut?  (That said, I personally *hate* it when websites pull trickery, unless it's to make it work like that action normally would).  Consider whether this is something that you actually need to do.

Comment: *“but if the user selects the text entered in the second datalist, right click and select CUT, the <span> is not updated.”* You probably have a `keydown`/`keyup`/`keypress` event listener that should be an `input` event listener.